# The method clone() from the type Object is not visible

Tags: clone

for the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong with this code, please help.  I have three classes, GeometricObject, Octagon which extends GeometricObject and TestOctagon which is being used to test the Octagon class.  When I run the TestOctagon class I get this error:

The method clone() from the type Object is not visible

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class GeometricObject {

    private String color = "white";
    private boolean filled;


    protected GeometricObject() {
    }

    protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public abstract double getArea();

    public abstract double getPerimeter();
}
```

---

```
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.lang.Cloneable;

public class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<Octagon>, Cloneable{

    double side;    

    public Octagon() {
    }

    public Octagon(double side) {
    this.side = side;
    }

    public Octagon(double side, String color, boolean filled) {
        this.side = side;
        setColor(color);
        setFilled(filled);
    }

    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return (2+4/Math.sqrt(2))*side*side;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 8*side;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Octagon o) {
        if (getArea() > o.getArea())
            return 1;
        else if (getArea() < o.getArea())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestOctagon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GeometricObject oc1 = new Octagon(5);
        System.out.println(oc1.getArea());
        System.out.println(oc1.getPerimeter());
        GeometricObject oc2 = (GeometricObject)oc1.clone();

    }

}
```

Comment: the GeometricObject  is not clonable   only Octagon

Answer (score 0):

Don,
Please note that the access specifier for method Object::clone() is protected. It is not accessible from your TestOctagon class as you are invoking this method on object of type GeometriObject (oc1) where the clone method is still protected as neither it or its super classes have overridden it. Try moving the clone method from Octagon class to GeometriObject class. Please retain the public access specifier. Refer this sample on how to do it http://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning

Comment: You say its protected, is there a way to make it unprotected so I can have it in the octagon class still?

Comment: Oops... I see that you have already overwritten the clone method in Octagon class. However, you are invoking the clone method on object of type GeometriObject (oc1) for whom the clone is still protected. Try moving the clone method to GeometricObject class and it should work fine. Have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Why isnt clone() being overriden in Octagon?

Comment: It got overridden here. But its not available from an instance variable of type GeometricObject as at that place (Check your class definition) it still (by-default) has protected access. You could try moving the overridden clone method from Octagon class to GeometricObject and your code should just work fine. Paste the errors if any you come across